# Doxygen TAGFILES will not link to external documentation

Tags: doxygen

TAGFILES in my Doxyfile will not link to external documentation.

In a generated configuration file by 'doxygen -g'

```
~/tests/libd/Doxyfile
```

The following lines were modified from the original as:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "libd"
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = libd.tag
```

Running 'doxygen' resulted in a file

```
~/tests/libd/libd.tag
```

and a subdirectory containing some html pages

```
~/tests/libd/html/
```

In another directory, another generated configuration file by 'doxygen -g'

```
~/tests/app/Doxyfile
```

was modified from the original as:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "app"
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
TAGFILES               = ../libd/libd.tag=../../libd/html
```

Running 'doxygen' resulted a subdirectory containing some html pages

```
~/tests/app/html/
```

However, the above html pages do not contain a link to the 'libd' html.
Changing the TAGFILES line to be

```
TAGFILES               =~/tests/libd/libd.tag=~/tests/libd/html
```

or

```
TAGFILES               = ../libd/libd.tag=../libd/html
```

did not make any differences.

Searched online a lot, but could not find any clue. Was it my doxygen version problem? Or my configuration mistakes? Please advice. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No sure about it, but maybe a level of "..: is missing in the line"../libd/libd.tag=../../libd/html", shouldn't this be "../libd/libd.tag=../../../libd/html" or "libd/libd.tag=../../libd/html". Compare example in manual Chapter 17 "Link to external documentation".

Comment: Neither "../libd/libd.tag=../../../libd/html" nor "libd/libd.tag=../../libd/html" worked. The latter even results in error message "error: Tag file `libd/libd.tag' does not exist or is not a file. Skipping it...".